# Initiate actions from messages on mobile in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing an app with a messaging extension that's invoked from the message context. In the web client, it appears just fine in the messages overflow menu under "Take action."

But when I tried it in the mobile client on my Android device, I didn't see it. Is that expected? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the overflow menu on my Android, and the result of opening it. There's no "Take action."

[image]

Comment: you can take a look at schema version of the menifest, Is it fine for your Android app. Maybe the web client can handle it, but Android client with the version can not do it.

Comment: The schema version in my manifest is 1.5. The version of my Android client is 1416/1.0.0.2019091701

Comment: There is some workaround for initiate actions in messaging extensions for android  devices, We do not have any ETA to share.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, Is there any particular ETA for message action on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message Actions on Mobile are not currently supported. We are working on this but we do not have a firm ETA to share with you!!

Comment: Is there any particular ETA for message action on mobile devices?